# How to know for how long the edit ban is going to last?

Tags: support, banning, edit-ban

I have been temporarily banned from suggesting edits, since more than a week now, and I would like to know if there is a way to see the number of days I still have to wait for this ban to end ?

I got this ban when trying to edit tags; the thing is that we must edit excerpts to do so, but their description is often rejected because it doesn't bring more information, which I understand.

Comment: Probably a month? So about less than 23 days left.

Comment: Apparently the ban is now over, so i don't really know how this works